# Print ascii character on screen

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am writing a bootloader in assembly (NASM instruction set), but for some reason it doesn't show any letter.

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

JMP $ 

MOV AL, 0x65
MOV AH, 0x0E
MOV BL, 0x07
MOV BH, 0x00

INT 0x10

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
DW 0xAA55
```

All I see is the _ cursor.

Comment: Isn't `JMP $` an endless loop?

Comment: No.  It jumps to itself, and it's before the other instructions.  You would have found this out yourself if you had used a debugger (e.g. in bochs or qemu).  See also the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: Oh, thank you. I removed it and it works now.

Comment: In `TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0` `$` is the current program counter, and `$$` is the program counter at the beginning of the section (in this case the beginning of the file). `$$` in this case would be 7c00h. `($-$$)` then would be the current number of bytes and data emitted already. `510-($-$$)` would the number of bytes to pad out the file to 510 bytes. The TIMES effectively fills out the space between where the program counter was up to the 510th byte using `db 0` (effectively zero fill). The the boot signature is written starting at byte 510 and 511 creating a 512 binary image.

Comment: You should have put the `JMP $` as the last instruction of your bootloader program (just after the `INT 0x10`). This would have prevented your bootloader from wandering across memory trying to execute random garbage/data instructions that happened to be in memory (that could lead to bizarre behaviour, reboots, hangs etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JMP $
```

Jumps to itself. Removing it will let the other code run