# What is the joke behind "goto $"?

Tags: assembly

I was on the phone with someone, when they were talking about prefering assembly to higher level languages. They mentioned liking the goto statement, to which I replied that it leads to spaghetti code. They replied with something like "goto $". I said that goto can give off code smell. They laughed, and said people don't normally get that joke.

Well, I didn't get it. Does anyone know what that person was talking about, in regards to "goto $"? What was the joke there? I feel silly asking this, but my Google searches didn't turn up anything helpful.

Comment: Maybe `jmp $` which in some assemblers is an infinite loop where `$` is the current program counter so `jmp $` keeps jumping back to the beginning of the jump instruction.

Comment: Hi Trevor Hickey, I noticed you made a slight edit to my question. From my reputation you can tell I don't know how this site works quite yet. Is there something undesirable about adding a polite send off on a question? I often do it without thinking, and it is at least the second time it has happened to me.

Comment: Some people remove them, they are superfluous. There is a Meta question along that lines with some answers here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @TeckFudge Stack Overflow distinguishes itself from typical fora by focussing on questions and answers. Greetings, signatures and other personal things are off topic and should not be placed in questions or answers.

Comment: Funny timing, just the very next question with #assembly was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085205/print-ascii-character-on-screen (`jmp $` endless loop bug).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In assembly `$` is a special character that represents the current value of the program counter, so `goto $` means  "jump to the current position", which results in an endless loop. I remember a similar joke in BASIC, it was something like `10 GOTO 10`.

Comment: In the BASIC interpreter on the Casio CFX-9850 I had in high school, the program `Lbl 1; While 0; Goto 1;` would hang the calculator to the point where you had to press the reset-button on the back.